# Execute 2 methods c++ and c# at same time Unity

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I have exported my native code in c++ into a dll and imported it in a c# script in unity. The C++ code reproduces music from a wav file. In the scene in unity I have a human head that can be rotated pressing the arrow keys. What I want to do is to synchronise both methods. I want to reproduce the music at the same time that I rotate the head because in a future,the music will change depending on the head rotation.

For the moment, when I run the Unity game, the music starts playing and once its done, I can start playing rotating the humans head. Not before.

Here is my code:

Audio.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" {    
    EXPORT void initialize(std::string soundFilePaths[]);
    EXPORT void setSourcePosition(std::string soundFilePath, float x, float y, float z);
    EXPORT void play();
    EXPORT void stop();
    EXPORT void setListenerRotation(float x, float y, float z);
}

class Audio {

public:

static Audio& instance() {  // Singleton
    static Audio INSTANCE;
    return INSTANCE;
}

void initialize(std::string soundFilePaths[]);
void setSourcePosition(std::string soundFilePath, float x, float y, float z);
void play();
void stop();
void setListenerRotation(float x, float y, float z);
~Audio();

private:    
    Audio();
};
```

Audio.cpp:

```
#include "Buffer.h"
#include "MonoSample.h"
#include "AudioDevice.h"
#include "Audio.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

#include <thread>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define NUMCHANNELS    2
#define OUTBUFSIZE  1024    
#define CREATEWAVFILE true


extern "C" {    

    void initialize(const char *soundFilePaths[], bool continuous) {    
        Audio::instance().initialize(soundFilePaths,continuous);        
    }

    void setSourcePosition(const char *soundFilePath, float x, float y, float z) {
        Audio::instance().setSourcePosition(soundFilePath, x, y, z);
    }

    void play() {
        Audio::instance().play();
    }

    void stop() {
        Audio::instance().stop();
    }

    void setListenerRotation(float x, float y, float z) {
        Audio::instance().setListenerRotation(x, y, z);
    }
}

float degree;
int numCanals;

Buffer channel[NUMCHANNELS];                            // Input buffer
unsigned char buffer[OUTBUFSIZE];                       // Ouput buffer
wavHdr header, *pheader;
FILE* outFile;                                          // Create output ( wave format) file
AudioDevice ad;


Audio::Audio()
{
}

Audio::~Audio()
{
}

void Audio::initialize(const char *soundFilePaths[], bool continuous)
{   
    char nom[20];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMCHANNELS; i++)
    {
        sprintf(nom, "%02d.wav", i + 1);
        string fitxer(nom);
        string path = WAVBASEPATH + fitxer;
        if (!channel[i].openFile(path, i))      //obre i llegeix bytes (fread)
        {
            /*cout << "ERROR [" << i + 1 << "]";*/
            ExitProcess(1);
        }
    }

    int inSampleRate = channel[0].getHeader().samplesPerSec;        
    int inSampleLen = channel[0].getHeader().bitsPerSample;
    int inNumberOfCn = channel[0].getHeader().numOfChan;            

    ad.iniAudioDevice(inSampleRate, inSampleLen, 2);                
    ad.setVolume50p();                                              

}

void Audio::setSourcePosition(const char *soundFilePath, float x, float y, float z)
{

}

void Audio::play()
{       
        while (1)
        {
            long readBytes;
            readBytes = channel[0].ReadInputBufferBlock(buffer, OUTBUFSIZE, channel, NUMCHANNELS, 1, false);            

            if (readBytes > 0)
            {
                ad.writeAudio((LPSTR)buffer, sizeof(buffer));           
            }
            else
                break;
        }
}

void Audio::stop()
{
    while (ad.waveFreeBlockCount < BLOCK_COUNT)                     
        Sleep(10);

    ad.closeAudioDevice();
}
```

Here is the C# script in Unity:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class AudioPlugin : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioContainer[] audioContainers;
    public Transform headGeometry;
    public float rotationSpeed = 50;
    public float maxYRotation = 90;
    public float minYRotation = -90;

    float _currentYRotation;


    void Start()
    {
        _currentYRotation = headGeometry.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
        string[] filePaths = GetAllFilePathsFromClips();
        AudioPluginConnection.Initialize(filePaths);
        AudioPluginConnection.Play();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        TurnHeadWithInput();
        UpdateListenerRotation();
        UpdateSoundPositions();
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        AudioPluginConnection.Stop();
    }

    void TurnHeadWithInput()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        horizontal *= Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed;
        _currentYRotation = Mathf.Clamp(_currentYRotation + horizontal, minYRotation, maxYRotation);
        Vector3 eulerAngles = headGeometry.rotation.eulerAngles;
        eulerAngles.y = _currentYRotation;
        headGeometry.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(eulerAngles);
    }

    void UpdateListenerRotation()
    {
        Vector3 eulerAngles = headGeometry.rotation.eulerAngles;
        AudioPluginConnection.SetListenerRotation(eulerAngles.x, eulerAngles.y, eulerAngles.y);
    }

    void UpdateSoundPositions()
    {
        foreach (AudioContainer container in audioContainers)
        {
            Vector3 position = container.source.position;
            AudioPluginConnection.SetSourcePosition(container.filePath, position.x, position.y, position.z);
        }
    }

    string[] GetAllFilePathsFromClips()
    {
        List<string> audioFilePaths = new List<string>();
        foreach (AudioContainer container in audioContainers)
        {
            audioFilePaths.Add(container.filePath);
        }
        return audioFilePaths.ToArray();
    }    
}

[System.Serializable]
public class AudioContainer
{
    public AudioClip clip;
    public Transform source;
    //Dont forget, that you have to copy the Audio Folder in the 
    //Unity Editor to the *_Data Folder in your builded Project!!! Quan construim projecte
    public string filePath { get { return Application.dataPath + "/Audio/" + clip.name + ".wav"; } }
}

public class AudioPluginConnection
{
    [DllImport("AudioPlugin", EntryPoint = "test")]
    public static extern int Test();
    [DllImport("AudioPlugin", EntryPoint = "initialize")]
    public static extern void Initialize(string[] soundFilePaths);
    [DllImport("AudioPlugin", EntryPoint = "setSourcePosition")]
    public static extern void SetSourcePosition(string soundFilePath, float x, float y, float z);
    [DllImport("AudioPlugin", EntryPoint = "play")]
    public static extern void Play();
    [DllImport("AudioPlugin", EntryPoint = "stop")]
    public static extern void Stop();
    [DllImport("AudioPlugin", EntryPoint = "setListenerRotation")]
    public static extern void SetListenerRotation(float x, float y, float z);
}
```

I think I need to create a parallel thread to the main one in unity to be able to do both actions but I am not sure and I dont know how.

The function AudioPluginConnection.play() is the one that reproduces the sound and the function TurnHeadWithInput() the one which rotates the head.

My goal is to be able that while pressing the buttons that rotates the head, the music sounds as well. In a future, depending on the head rotation, I will apply an algorithm to the samples of the wav file and reproduce it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you do need to create a separate thread and run your c++ functions from that thread. I'd recommend a few sources to learn from about threading:
Bunny83 from Unity Answers responded [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/180243/threading-in-unity.html) about a few important things about threading in Unity.

Threading is not implemented in Unity but in C# so I'd reccomend reading the MSDN tutorial on threading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx)